# Is it possible to import an external bean configuration xml file into resources.groovy?

Tags: spring, grails

In my current grails application, I have spring beans defined in resources.groovy. Now I also have an xml file with a bunch of beans already defined, and I would like to use them as is instead of recreating every single bean in the bean dsl.

Is this possible at all ? Is there an equivalent of the xml import tag in grails bean dsl ?
I thought about adding the import ... in applicationContext.xml but I'm not sure that's the right place to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Philippe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can import the beans in an XML file into `resources.groovy`using

```
beans = {
    importBeans('classpath:/applicationContext-services.xml')
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work... do I have to do that inside the existing beans closure or after it ?

Comment: Still can't make it work with that one... none of the beans in my xml file get loaded.

Comment: @Philippe My guess is that you haven't specified the path to your XML file properly. I use this in my Grails app and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename it to `resources.xml` and put it in the same folder. The xml version is still supported, but it's not automatically created like the Groovy version is.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could still do this, but I thought I couldn't make resources.groovy and resources.xml coexist. It seems like it's possible...

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work on grails 1.3.7 I actually had to do something like this;

```
beans {

   switch(Environment.current) {

      case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
         importBeans('file:grails-app/conf/spring/messaging.xml')
         break
      default:
         importBeans 'classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/messaging.xml'
         break
   }

}
```

I needed the * after classpath in order for it to be picked up when running in the application server. Doesn't work in development though hence the different accessor for it

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html for documentation on the matching syntax.