# Importing an externalised Groovy DSL Spring bean configuration into Grails resources.groovy

Tags: spring, grails

I have a Grails application with Spring beans configured in my resources.groovy file. I would like to know if it is possible to import my bean configuration from an external source on the file system but still keep them in the Groovy DSL style.

I am aware the it is possible to import a bean config from an XML file as detailed in this post "[Is it possible to import an external bean configuration xml file into resources.groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823998/is-it-possible-to-import-an-external-bean-configuration-xml-file-into-resources)" but would like to know how to do this with Groovy DSL bean config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like this is possible with Groovy DSL in much the same way as importing a Spring XML config file.

[This post](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2010/10/13/grails-quicky-splitting-up-resources-groovy/) has a good explanation of how to achieve it.

Simply import the external spring config into your resources.groovy file like so:

```
beans = {
    importBeans('file:grails-app/conf/spring/common.xml')
    importBeans('file:grails-app/conf/spring/job-definitions.xml')
    importBeans('file:grails-app/conf/spring/integration.groovy')
    // ...
}
```

Then your integration.groovy file should look something like this.

```
beans {
    myBean(MyBean) { bean ->
        property1 = 123
        property2 = "abc"
    }
}
```

It's important to note that in the spring file you import there is no `=` sign after `beans`. If you specify `beans = { ..... }` your beans will not be imported.